# How to accurately measure time difference xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, time

I need to super accurately measure time difference in xcode. I'm fairly new to Xcode and Objective C but I'm not really sure how to start it.

I need to measure the time difference between when a sound is played through the speaker and when the sound is recorded through the mic.

I'm not sure how to measure time this accurately as it will be a very short amount of time.

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This is almost impossible to do with a single time measurement, since there are two unknown latencies (one for output and one for input). All you can really measure is the total round trip latency.

Answer (score 2):

The most precise clock is probably `mach_absolute_time`---returning ticks since the device was last booted. See [this Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html) from Apple for an example of how to use it and convert it into a nicer unit.